# Flutter always running pub upgrade every time i cold start(as well as git error showning in cmd and run window)

Tags: git, android-studio, flutter, dart

As stated in the title, flutter runs pub upgrade every time i cold start an app. It takes a long time every time it does that, and as far as im concerned, it shouldn't do that in the first place.
I see this every time i start an app

```
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
```

Git error message is something that pops up every time as well. I had problems installing git at the start and i had this exact same error message too. But it does the same in cmd too, no matter what command i use. If anyone knows how to fix this, i would greatly appreciate the help.
Here is what i get when running flutter doctor -v in cmd:

```
operable program or batch file.
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1316], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.6 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 9b2d32b605 (8 days ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 2f0af37152
    • Dart version 2.10.5


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • M2007J20CG (mobile) • 3dc8c919 • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: I will recommend you to check if you have properly installed flutter and dart library in visual studio code.

Comment: Also having this issue Mar 22, also on windows.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the git error because you don't have Git installed in your Windows OS.

To install Git, go to this [link](https://git-scm.com/downloads) and download Git on your system.

For the Flutter Warning, you need to add the Flutter Plugin in your Android Studio(AS).

To install the Plugin these:

1. Open Android Studio.
2. Go to `File` -> `Settings` -> Search for `Plugins`
3. Search for the Flutter plugin and click Install.
4. Click Yes when prompted to install the Dart plugin, it is necessary to use Flutter.
5. Click Restart when prompted.

You seem to be starting Flutter so I advice you to read the Flutter Documentation. Every step is clearly defined there.

Comment: I have already installed git, and i have flutter currently installed, otherwise i wouldn't be able to run my apps without it(i reinstalled it only an hour ago, and it doesnt solve my problem)

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem before and installing git then add it path to system variable solved the problem. Just make sure you can run 'git' command

Comment: First line of the existing ansswer: `You are getting the git error because you don't have Git installed`

Comment: yes, it is, but just install git only not solve the problem, you must add it path to system variable, so the terminal/command line can recognize 'git' command